# Conditional foreign key in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-design

i have one table called as PartyChannel having following columns

```
 ID, ChannelID, ChannelType
```

`ChannelID` stores `MailID` or `PhoneID` or `EmailID` depending on the `ChannelType`.

so how can i create a foreign key between PartyChannel and all three tables (Mail, Email and Phone) depending on the channelType.

Comment: MailID, PhoneID, EmailID are three distinct domains and cannot, should not be modelled using a single ChannelID column. This is fundamental stuff.

Answer (score 19):

You can use [PERSISTED COMPUTED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx) columns with a case statement but in the end, it buys you nothing but overhead.

The best solution would be to model them as three distinct values to start with.

```
CREATE TABLE Mails (MailID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)
CREATE TABLE Phones (PhoneID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)
CREATE TABLE Emails (EmailID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY)

CREATE TABLE PartyChannel (
  ID INTEGER NOT NULL
  , ChannelID INTEGER NOT NULL
  , ChannelType CHAR(1) NOT NULL
  , MailID AS (CASE WHEN [ChannelType] = 'M' THEN [ChannelID] ELSE NULL END) PERSISTED REFERENCES Mails (MailID)
  , PhoneID AS  (CASE WHEN [ChannelType] = 'P' THEN [ChannelID] ELSE NULL END) PERSISTED REFERENCES Phones (PhoneID)
  , EmailID AS  (CASE WHEN [ChannelType] = 'E' THEN [ChannelID] ELSE NULL END) PERSISTED REFERENCES Emails (EmailID)
)
```

**Disclaimer**

*just because you can doesn't mean you should.*

Comment: This is pretty wild. Does it work in all the major SQL implementations?

Comment: @Mark: it works with SQL Server 2005 & 2008. Other than that, I honestly have no idea, it was a good mental excercise <g>. A disclaimer might be in order though: *just because you can doesn't mean you should!*

Comment: It does work in SQL Server although your ChannelType should be a char or varchar rather than an int.  Again - +1 - thanks.  Pretty interesting and unusual stuff.  I still agree with @onedaywhen that this isn't a good design but I appreciate the lesson in offbeat SQL that you have provided!

Comment: Oops - just saw your comment.  RE: "just because you can..." - you said it right.  It truly never ceases to amaze me just how much you can do with SQL.

Comment: @Mark, thanks for spotting that. I have fixed the ChannelType type.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers, You suggest to not use this. What's the down side?

Comment: @FLICKER - the comment from onedaywhen explains that better than I could: *MailID, PhoneID, EmailID are three distinct domains and cannot, should not be modelled using a single ChannelID column.*

Answer (score 8):

Sub-type `Email, Mail, Phone` to the `Channel`.

[image]

Comment: This is the gen-spec pattern, as represented in a relational model.  The diagram illustrates the keys nicely.  Good job.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, you cannot do this with standard foreign keys.  However, you could implement something to help ensure data integrity by using triggers.  Essentially, the trigger would check for the presence of a "foreign key" on the referenced table - the value that must be present - whenever there is an insert or update on the referencing table.  Similarly, a delete from the referenced table could have a trigger that checks for records on the referencing table that use the key being deleted.

Update: Although I went right for the "answer" I agree with the comment left by @onedaywhen that this is actually a design-caused problem that should probably make you reconsider your design. That is, you should have three different columns rather than one column referencing three tables.  You would just leave the other two columns null when one is filled which, in turn, would let you use standard foreign keys.  Any concern that this would "use too much space" is silly; it represents a severe case of premature optimization - it just isn't going to matter.